${\rm SL}_2(\mathbb C)$-equivariant K-theory of $\mathbb C P^1$
Consider the action of ${\rm SL}_2(\mathbb C)$ on $\mathbb C P^1$ induced by the action of 2×2 matrices on 2-vectors. Is it true that $K^{{\rm SL}_2(\mathbb C)}(\mathbb C P^1)$ is $\mathbb C[t,t^{-1}]$? If this is true, can the class of $\mathcal O(1)$ (with the equivariant structure as the inverse of the tautological line bundle with its natural equivariant structure) be taken to be equal to $t$? Does this mean that every vector bundle $V=\oplus O(n)$ on $\mathbb C P^1$ has a unique ${\rm SL}_2(\mathbb C)$-equivariant structure (as the direct sum of equivariant structures on subbundles $\mathcal O(n)$ obtained as tensor products of $\mathcal O(1)$ or $\mathcal O(-1)$)?

No, it is the further invariants by the natural action of the Weyl group \mathfrak{S}_2$, i. e., the cyclic group of order 2.

This invariant subring is the polynomial ring in one variable $t+t^{-1}$.

@JasonStarr Thank you! Do you mean that $K^{\rm SL_2(\mathbb C)}(\mathbb C P^1)$ is $\mathbb C[t+t^{-1}]$?

@JasonStarr Does this mean that the tautological line bundle on $\mathbb C P^1$ does not admit an $\rm SL_2$-equivariant structure?

@JasonStarr I also thought that $K^{\rm SL_2}(pt)=\mathbb C[t+t^{-1}]$, does this mean that it is the same as $K^{\rm SL_2}(\mathbb C P^1)$?

Since CP^1 = SL_2(C)/B where B is a borel subgroup, the SL_2(C)-equivariant K-theory of CP^1 is just the B-equivariant K-theory of a point. This is in turn the same as the S^1-equivariant K-theory of a point, which is Z[t^(pm 1)]. This also makes it clear that the class t^n is represented by O(n).

Sorry, I was thinking of equivariant cohomology of a point, not equivariant K-theory.

By the Atiyah-Bott Localization Theorem (or something simpler), the equivariant cohomology of $\mathbb{CP}^1$, as a module over the of the equivariant cohomology of a point, is isomorphic to a free rank-$2$ module, at least after tensoring with the fraction field of the equivariant cohomology of a point.  This is completely consistent with passing to $\mathfrak{S}_2$-invariants, since the original ring is a free rank-$2$ module over the ring of $\mathfrak{S}_2$-invariants.

I am just posting the comments as one answer (I am happy for somebody else to answer).  For a maximal torus $\mathbb{G}_m \hookrightarrow \mathbf{SL}_2$, the $\mathbb{G}_m$-equivariant K-theory of a point equals the ring of virtual representations of $\mathbb{G}_m$, i.e., the group ring $\mathbb{Z}[t,t^{-1}]$, where $t$ is the K-theory class of the tautological representation $\mathbb{G}_m \xrightarrow{=} \mathbf{GL}_1$.  The induced homomorphism from the $\mathbf{SL}_2$-equivariant K-theory of a point to the $\mathbb{G}_m$-equivariant K-theory of a point depends on the choice of maximal torus, but the homomorphism is an isomorphism whose image equals $\mathbb{Z}[t,t^{-1}]^{\mathfrak{S}_2} = \mathbb{Z}[t+t^{-1}]$ independent of this choice.
As a module over the ring $\mathbb{Z}[t+t^{-1}]$, the $\mathbf{SL}_2$-equivariant K-theory of $\mathbb{P}^1$ is free of rank $2$.  As explained by user @skd, as an algebra over this ring it is isomorphic to the $\mathbb{Z}[t+t^{-1}]$-algebra $\mathbb{Z}[t,t^{-1}]$.
Edit.  I am adding the important point noted by user @Wilberd.van.der.Kallen that the structure of equivariant vector bundle (in Mumford's notation, $\textbf{SL}_2$-linearization) is not unique.

However, the ${\rm SL}_2(\mathbb C)$ equivariant structure on a vector bundle is not unique: It corresponds with a $B$ equivariant structure on the fiber over the origin. The action of the Borel group $B$ is not determined by the K-theory class.

More specifically, if $B$ is the stabiliser of the origin, then there are two actions on $ \mathcal O(0)\oplus \mathcal O(0)$. One where $B$ acts in the usual way on $\mathbb C^2$, the other with $B$ acting trivially on the fiber.

The structure sheaf is too rigid, as a nonequivariant sheaf, to support several $\mathbf{SL}_2$-linarizations.

@WilberdvanderKallen Thanks, I corrected it.
